# MISRA Rule 10.4 Violation

Tags: c, misra

I'm getting the next MISRA error:
Rule-10.4 The operands of this equality operator are expressions of different 'essential type' categories (Boolean and unsigned).
The code is showed below:

```c
#define TRUE (1!=0)
#define FALSE (0!=0)
typedef unsigned char   boolean;


boolean active;
getActive(&active);

if (TRUE == active)  <<<<<<<<<<<< HEre is the conflicting line
{

// DO Something
}
```

If I remove the TRUE :

```c
if (active)
```

MISTA Rule 14.4 appears: "Controlling expression is not an 'essentially Boolean'  expression"

So I cannot figure out the solution,

I see that using

```c
#define TRUE 1U
#define FALSE 0U
```

solves the problem but I'm afraid I cannot afford this solution since I'm using a big inherited code from a 3rd party using the (1!=0) expression. 
I guess that expression is more 'smart' and portable since in some systems the meaning of TRUE/ FALSE might chenge to 0/1 but I wonder if I can keep the:

```c
#define TRUE (1!=0)
#define FALSE (0!=0)
```

and write my conditional expressions in a manner to cope with the MISRA issues

Comment: I want to point out that it's very dangerous to define your own boolean type. Many truthy expressions evaluate to non-truthy values through assignment. MISRA will mitigate some of this, but it's still dangerous.

Comment: "I guess that expression is more 'smart' and portable since in some systems the meaning of TRUE/ FALSE might chenge to 0/1" No. The meanings of true/false cannot change. Please drop these misconceptions about C. People define macros for this not because they may change, but either because they wrongly believe they may change, or because they find the macros more readable.

Comment: If you can, use C11 and the `_Bool` type rather than rolling your own bools.

Comment: Have you tried `(unsigned char)TRUE`?

Comment: @R.. It's gonna have to be `bool` from stdbool.h, otherwise the MISRA analyser won't realize what `true` and `false` are. Comparing `_Bool` against value `1` etc will cause MISRA violations.

Comment: If nothing else, get rid of `if(TRUE == active)`, and change it to `if(active)`, because the former is an accident waiting to happen.  MISRA can help, but if you find yourself wanting or needing to use the `== TRUE` form, something has gone badly wrong and is getting worse...

Comment: @R.. Last I'd heard, MISRA doesn't accept C11 yet.  `_Bool` should be available in C99, though,

Comment: Oh yes, C99. Sorry I like forgot C99 was a thing, now that it's 20 years old. :-)

Comment: And yes, like @SteveSummit said, absolutely do not use `==` operator with self-rolled boolean types that don't have `_Bool` semantics. It's a disaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for the answers and comments.

Unfortunately  I'm not allowed to use stdbool.h , I'm using an AUTOSAR (automotive) stack and they don't use any of the standard libraries.

I'd prefer don't to trick the MISRA tool to indicate the boolean type, I thinkit would be something that we'd have to export to any PC of the team (ad-hoc solution)

Thanks to  @R about the (1 != 0) clarification; it makes no sense , *C* is *C* (not bash or whatever where the true might be 0) , and *true* will be always 1, so unless you are ignorant about the bool value in your programming language the definition as a expression is useless.

I think that for my porpuses the best solution would be to redefine the macros as:

```c
#define TRUE (1U)
#define FALSE (0U)
```

I've seen the AUTOSAR stack gives me the option to redefine this values in a *Integration* file

And this way I keep the compatibility with all my Application code and the existing AUTOSA stack and also I don't need to change anything in the inherited code.

Answer (score 5):

Your MISRA checker is unable to determine that these are your boolean type.

In case you are stuck with C90 *and only then*: you need to inform your tool somehow about which custom bool type you are using. Otherwise it won't be able to tell what these macros are for.

Otherwise, simply use `stdbool.h`. There are very few excuses not to in the year 2019.

Comment: migrating my comment here: using `<stdbool.h>` also provides C++ compatibility which is generally good.

Comment: I would go farther and say there is *no* excuse not to use a compiler new enough that it supports `stdbool` -- or at least, not in a shop that is mandating MISRA compliance.  Any excuse not to use a modern compiler would also be an excuse not to use MISRA; every reason to mandate MISRA's extra error-checking is also a reason to mandate a modern compiler's extra error-checking.

Comment: @SteveSummit Not for new projects, certainly. But there's a whole lot of older C90 projects with MISRA-C:2004 still being maintained.

Comment: As he pointed out, AUTOSAR compliance does not allow stbhool.h